# Scala.js + React: "sbt run" shows "Target container is not a DOM element"

Tags: scala, reactjs, sbt, scala.js

I am using scala.js and the japgolly react library.

I have seen a lot of threads about the same problem caused by having the scripts not at the end of the body part, or misspelling the element id name. But my HTML is fine and **it renders perfectly**. It works.

But I also wanted to use: *sbt run* ... for testing. Based on the best practices (step 6) of the scala.js basic [tutorial](http://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/)  . Unfortunately unlike the real page, the *sbt run* returns:

```
[error]     throw error;
[error]     ^
[error] Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

The reference is to a simple ReactDOM:

```
ReactDOM.render(<.div("foo"), document.getElementById("fooid"))
```

Not sure that I needed to, but I have RuntimeDOM in my jsDependencies. And I also installed via npm the jsdom. Hopefully that is not a problem.

Any idea what I need to do so the *sbt run* works as well?
Thank you

Comment: I'm not understanding why you want to use `sbt run` with a Scala.js project. Can you explain, please? To me a Scala.js project is basically meant to produce a JavaScript library that runs in the browser.

Comment: Following best practices of scala.js, this is meant for testing purposes. As explained on the scala.js basic tutorial. http://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/ ... step 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React throwing error because there is no element with id `fooid` in your test environment.

```
val fooDiv = dom.document.createElement("div")

fooDiv.id = "fooid"

dom.document.body.appendChild(fooDiv)
```

Comment: Thank you @invariant. That could have been the cause, but as mentioned my html works. The id exists and my app is rendered well. The probelm is only with the sbt run. See step 6 of the basic tutorial for a similar scenario: http://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/ ... here though ReactDom.render is not recognized.

Comment: In `sbt run` your HTML file is not used. You have to create the critical parts of it using code, as @invariant showed.

Comment: I see. Thank you!